# Temporary password issuance does not work properly after Android promotion launch

Tags: android, retrofit2, nodemailer

We implemented a function to issue a temporary password to the user's e-mail using Retrofit. In the tester mode, the temporarily issued password was stored in the user database, so it was possible to log in with the changed password. However, after the production launch, a temporary password is sent to the user, and if they try to log in with that password, a message indicating that the password is incorrect will appear. When I check the user database, it is confirmed that the password has been changed to a temporary password issued by our side. What's the problem?

I am currently using `Retrofit` and `Nodemailer`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the Login API Using Postman or Insomnia. If the issue exists then the Problem with the server side.
2. In Server side,Check the same encryption scheme & salt(used to encrypt temporary Password) is used while checking the password. Passwords won't match if different encryption scheme(& salt) is used while creation and checking.
3. If the problem is not in server side, then Check the retrofit is using the correct authentication method & Exception is handled correctly in retrofit

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was solved, the reason was the conflict between ```proguard``` and ```Retrofit2```.